# EACCES: permission denied, open

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, digital-ocean

Can someone help me? My Problem is the following: I have a nodejs application that I published on digitalocean with docker, but when I try to publish an article with an image I receive the following error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open 'uploads /9d607de9b2483a9e92120979cfca666f'

Comment: Probably digitalocean do not give you access to their file system?

Comment: Are you sure you should have a space between `uploads` and `/`?

Comment: uploads is a Folder in my code